# How to use Javascript data append from jsp servlet data

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, append

Some Spring put a jsp file,
this jsp file includes a Javascript file.

The Javascript file is like this:

```
var data=${get some data from java}
    var input =$(input[name=getdata]).attr("value",data);

$('#objForm').append(input);
```

and I want append this data Spring modelandView controlled called `setViewName("file/call/jsp")`

and this jsp file gets  data by same name input element like this:

```
<input name="getdata" val=()/>

<input name="getdata" val=()/>

<input name="getdata" val=()/>

<input name="getdata" val=()/>
```

Which I wrote like this:

```
<form id="objForm" action="" >
<input type="text" name="getdata" value=""/>
    <input name="getdata" val=()/>

    <input name="getdata" val=()/>

    <input name="getdata" val=()/>

    <input name="getdata" val=()/>


</form>
```

How to change my javascript code?

This script didn't append the input element.

Comment: what kind of error you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for but how about this?

**EDIT: Added a second option. I hope it is what you are looking for.**

```js
// ************************************************************
// FRIST OPTION
// ************************************************************
/*
var data = [{
  "name": "Data1",
  "value": "THIS IS SOME DATA"
}, {
  "name": "Data2",
  "value": "THIS IS SOME OTHER DATA"
}, {
  "name": "Data3",
  "value": "more... 4566"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // This is the first way i recommended.
  //var input = "[" + i + "] <input type='text' name='" + data[i].name + "' value='" + data[i].value + "'><br>";

}
*/
// ************************************************************
// SECOND OPTION
// ************************************************************
// EDIT: If you want this format use like this you need to put 
// the input into quotations "" and the name with single 
// quotations ''

var data = "data here"; // get data from source
var input = $("input[name='getdata']").attr("value", data);

$('#objForm').append(input);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='objForm'>
  <input name="getdata"/> <!-- You can do it without writing val=() if you wanted to-->
  <input name="getdata" val=()/>
  <input name="getdata" val=()/>
  <input name="getdata" val=()/>
  <input name="getdata" val=()/>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you your advice  But 
 sever side increase element
em.. 
 var input =$(input[name=getdata]).attr("value",data); this data just number

and server side get array that data

how do i fix it?

Comment: Thank you so much. 
your advice will be help to me

Comment: No Problem. Good luck!